# Word OpenXML wp14:anchorId attribute causing Textbox alignement bug

Tags: c#, vb.net, ms-word, openxml, office-interop

So. Here is a hard question:

I developed a Word Plugin for Word 2007, and then upgraded it to Word 2010. It was stable in 2007, but, after the upgraded one important function stopped  to work, so I had to revert my changes.

The specific function which stopped takes the selected picture in the document, and adds a textbox by it's side, with specific formatting. (I'll provide the code at the end of the question)

The final version could be installed in both, 2007 and 2010, version, but would only work in 2007. Until today!... [suspence]

By accident, one client used the plugin to work on a document on Word 2010, and surprisingly, it managed to work!!

So I went to investigate the problem. I took a copy o a working document, and a non-working version of the same document, and compared the OpenXML of both.

Here is what I found:

**Working Document**

This is a picture markup on the working document:

```
<w:drawing>
    <wp:inline distT="0" distB="0" distL="0" distR="0">
        <wp:extent cx="3251200" cy="2285390"/>
        <wp:effectExtent l="19050" t="19050" r="25400" b="19685"/>
        <wp:docPr id="193" name="Imagem 48" descr="Elev. 4"/>
        <wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
            <a:graphicFrameLocks xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main"/>
        </wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
        <a:graphic xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
            <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
                <pic:pic xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
                    <pic:nvPicPr>
                        <pic:cNvPr id="0" name=""/>
                        <pic:cNvPicPr/>
                    </pic:nvPicPr>
                    <pic:blipFill>
                        <a:blip r:embed="rId33">
                            <a:lum/>
                        </a:blip>
                        <a:stretch>
                            <a:fillRect/>
                        </a:stretch>
                    </pic:blipFill>
                    <pic:spPr>
                        <a:xfrm>
                            <a:off x="0" y="0"/>
                            <a:ext cx="3251200" cy="2285390"/>
                        </a:xfrm>
                        <a:prstGeom prst="rect">
                            <a:avLst/>
                        </a:prstGeom>
                        <a:noFill/>
                        <a:ln w="19044" cmpd="sng">
                            <a:solidFill>
                                <a:srgbClr val="333333"/>
                            </a:solidFill>
                            <a:prstDash val="solid"/>
                        </a:ln>
                    </pic:spPr>
                </pic:pic>
            </a:graphicData>
        </a:graphic>
    </wp:inline>
</w:drawing>
```

**NOT Working Document**

This is the SAME picture markup on the non-working document:

```
<w:drawing>
    <wp:inline distT="0" distB="0" distL="0" distR="0" wp14:anchorId="0FC2E46A" wp14:editId="42C17A65">
        <wp:extent cx="3251200" cy="2285390"/>
        <wp:effectExtent l="19050" t="19050" r="25400" b="19685"/>
        <wp:docPr id="50" name="Imagem 50" descr="Elev. 1"/>
        <wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
            <a:graphicFrameLocks xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main"/>
        </wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
        <a:graphic xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
            <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
                <pic:pic xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
                    <pic:nvPicPr>
                        <pic:cNvPr id="0" name=""/>
                        <pic:cNvPicPr/>
                    </pic:nvPicPr>
                    <pic:blipFill>
                        <a:blip r:embed="rId24">
                            <a:lum/>
                        </a:blip>
                        <a:stretch>
                            <a:fillRect/>
                        </a:stretch>
                    </pic:blipFill>
                    <pic:spPr>
                        <a:xfrm>
                            <a:off x="0" y="0"/>
                            <a:ext cx="3251200" cy="2285390"/>
                        </a:xfrm>
                        <a:prstGeom prst="rect">
                            <a:avLst/>
                        </a:prstGeom>
                        <a:noFill/>
                        <a:ln w="19044" cmpd="sng">
                            <a:solidFill>
                                <a:srgbClr val="333333"/>
                            </a:solidFill>
                            <a:prstDash val="solid"/>
                        </a:ln>
                    </pic:spPr>
                </pic:pic>
            </a:graphicData>
        </a:graphic>
    </wp:inline>
</w:drawing>
```

The only difference, is in the second line, where the working document reads:

```
<wp:inline distT="0" distB="0" distL="0" distR="0">
```

and the other reads:

```
<wp:inline distT="0" distB="0" distL="0" distR="0" wp14:anchorId="0FC2E46A" wp14:editId="42C17A65">
```

So! The not working document picture have two extra attributes `wp14:anchorId` and `wp14:editId`.

**The Function:**

This is the method that adds and format the textbox to the picture.

```
Sub AddTextBox(ByVal picture As Word.InlineShape)
  Dim textBox As Word.Shape =
    ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox(
        Orientation:=Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal,
        Left:=picture.Width + 10,
        Top:=0,
        Width:=MarginWidth - picture.Width - 10,
        Height:=picture.Height,
        Anchor:=picture.Range.Paragraphs(1).Range)

With textBox
    .RelativeHorizontalPosition = Word.WdRelativeHorizontalPosition.wdRelativeHorizontalPositionMargin
    .RelativeVerticalPosition = Word.WdRelativeVerticalPosition.wdRelativeVerticalPositionParagraph

    .Line.DashStyle = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoLineDashStyle.msoLineSolid
    .Line.BackColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    .Line.Style = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoLineStyle.msoLineSingle
    .Line.Weight = 0.25

    .LockAnchor = True
End With
EndSub
```

**The Problem:**

The method above, as you can see, aligns the textbox to the Top of the paragraph wher the image is. The image is inline, therefore, the textbox top aligns to the top of the image. This is what happens in word 2007 and on the referred working document.

The problem is: When I run this method on the not working document, the textbox ends up aligned with the top of the PAGE. Without margin.

This working document is exceptional. All the others behave like the not-working one in Word 2010.

I've researched MSDN documentation, and there's no info about those attributes.

So please:

1. What are the attributes `wp14:anchorId` and `wp14:editId`?
2. And how to make Word stop generating them?
3. Or how to stop textboxes goingo to the top of the page when these attributes exist.

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score -1):

there are two types of tag inline and anchor.

```
<wp:anchor distT="0" distB="0" distL="114300" distR="114300" simplePos="0" relativeHeight="251658240" behindDoc="0" locked="0" layoutInCell="1" allowOverlap="1" wp14:anchorId="7E0D7E99" wp14:editId="66BEB3EF">
```

The given attributes wp14:anchorId and wp14:editId are related to anchor but I can see in your code, it is in inline tag.

```
<wp:inline distT="0" distB="0" distL="0" distR="0" wp14:anchorId="0FC2E46A" wp14:editId="42C17A65">
```

Inline tag should have only.

```
<wp:inline distT="0" distB="0" distL="0" distR="0" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing">
```

I think this will help others too.

Thanks.